Dual representation and proxies to achieve privacy in Lua
I am reading Programming in Lua, 4th edition with an intention to solve every exercise in that book. The last exercise in Chapter 21 p. 172 is the following (emphs are mine):

A variation of the dual representation is to implement objects using proxies (the section called “Tracking table accesses”). Each object is represented by an empty proxy table. An internal table maps proxies to tables that carry the object state. This internal table is not accessible from the outside, but methods use it to translate their self parameters to the real tables where they operate. Implement the Account example using this approach and discuss its pros and cons.

My solution is the following :
Account = {}

local proxyToAccount = {}

function Account:new ()
    local proxy = {}
    proxyToAccount[proxy] = { balance = 0 }
    setmetatable(proxy, self)
    self.__index = self
    return proxy
end

function Account:balance ()
    return proxyToAccount[self].balance
end

function Account:withdraw (v)
    proxyToAccount[self].balance = proxyToAccount[self].balance - v
end

function Account:deposit (v)
    proxyToAccount[self].balance = proxyToAccount[self].balance + v
end

return Account

Which is barely different from the example provided by the book itself (several pages above):
local balance = {}

Account = {}

function Account:withdraw (v)
    balance[self] = balance[self] - v
end

function Account:deposit (v)
    balance[self] = balance[self] + v
end

function Account:balance ()
    return balance[self]
end

function Account:new (o)
    o = o or {} -- create table if user does not provide one
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    balance[o] = 0 -- initial balance
    return o
end

return Account

I am asking for your opinion if I understand the exercise correctly and if my solution is a correct one. Thank you in advance !

Is your proxy just always empty table?

@darkfrei, yes it is: "Each object is represented by an empty proxy table." Of course, I could have allowed passing some "initial table" to the Account:new (like in the example from the book I showed) but I don't think it matters here.


If your solution is correct: if it works — then yes. 2. Your solution keeps a table with a single integer field, their keeps the integer field outright, without wrapping it with an additional table. In context of the task is does not matter, but your solution eats more memory which in theory might lead to efficiency deficiency in a real project.


You can store any values in the object, but you are using object just as unique key.

You did not create a proxy as it is described in Tracking table accesses you may want to go back an revisit that section. you did not produce "A variation of the dual representation" you just reproduced the same code but with balance renamed to proxyToAccount which I feel misses the point of the exercise.
You are intended to solve the problem using a proxy because it should produce a different result, then you can compare those results.
Here is an example using a proxy table. There is probably a better way to do this and I may come back and tweak it later.
local Account = {}
Account.__index = Account
function Account:withdraw (v)
    self.balance = self.balance - v
end

function Account:deposit (v)
    self.balance = self.balance + v
end

function Account:new()
  local protected = setmetatable({balance = 0}, Account)
  local proxy = {    
    deposit = function(self, v)
        protected:deposit(v)
    end,
    
    withdraw = function(self, v)
        protected:withdraw(v)
    end,
  }
  
  local meta = {
    __index = protected,
    __newindex = function (t,k,v)
      print("this table is read-only")
    end,
  }

  setmetatable(proxy, meta)
  return proxy
end

Then you make these calls with both implementations:
account = Account:new()
account:deposit(100)
print(account.balance)

what are the differences, how many indexes are done, what is the memory foot print, which is more secure, etc...
